# Include global functions in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource, vue-component

In my Vue.js application I want to have some global functions. For example a `callApi()` function which I can call every time I need access to my data.

What is the best way to include these functions so I can access it in all my components?

- Should I create a file functions.js and include it in my main.js?
- Should I create a Mixin and include it in my main.js?
- Is there a better option?

Comment: Maybe Vuex? http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/data-flow.html

Comment: Vuex us mainly to store data if I'm right? I don't think it is for creating global functions?

Comment: My thought was that you "need access to your data"; Vuex would provide that. Vuex itself can make the calls that fetch the data.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps my question was unclear, sorry. I meant global functions.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your best bet would be a Plugin, which lets you add features to the global vue system.

[from the [vuejs Docs]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)

```
MyPlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {

// 1. add global method or property
Vue.myGlobalMethod = ...

// 2. add a global asset
Vue.directive('my-directive', {})

// 3. add an instance method
Vue.prototype.$myMethod = ...

}
```

Then you would just add

```
Vue.use(MyPlugin)
```

in your code before calling your function.

```
Vue.myGlobalMethod(parameters);
```

or in your case

```
Vue.callApi(parameters);
```

Comment: Thank you. What exactly is the difference between Mixins and Plugins (for adding global functions)?

Comment: @Jordy the difference is that a mixin must be included in your mixin hash in your vm definition for each component that requires that functionality. A plugin makes it globally available in all your components, without requiring inclusion (since it extends the main Vue instance, each component you create already includes this functionality)

Comment: @Jordy Tremendus has it right, Mixins are limited functionality that's added to components separately which is what I'd normally use unless a large majority of my components need that function.

Comment: How to create plugin with webpack?

Comment: Is it the same process when using Nuxt?

Answer (score 42):

I have a file with function like a func.js
like below

```
export const func = {
   functionName: (data) => {
      return something  
    }
}
```

In main.js add 2 string

```
import {func} from './func.js'

Vue.prototype.$func = func
```

and you can use from all components if in script tag like below

```
this.$func.functionName(somedata)
```

or if template tag like

```
$func.functionName(somedata)
```

Comment: Like this answer since it's quite clear about "what" and "how" should I get it done.

Answer (score 7):

Mixins can be registered globally​ too. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin

Answer (score 0):

Very simle way is to declare function in window (if is web aplication)

```
window.myFunc = () => {
    console.log("Hello")
}

...

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted() {
      myFunc()
  }
})
```