# Unable to access Vue.js global function through plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to refactor some commonly used functions into a globally available Util plugin for my app. I followed the instructions from the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373047/include-global-functions-in-vue-js), but I'm not sure how to use it the functions in the template and Vue keeps complaining about an undefined method. Ideally I just want to call `isEmpty` from any child component.

#### util.js

```js
export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
      Vue.isEmpty = function (object) {
        return false // dummy function for now to check if method works
      }
  }
}
```

Also tried:

```js
Util.install = function (Vue, options) {
  Vue.isEmpty = function () {
    ...
  }
  // this doesn't work either
  // Vue.prototype.$isEmpty = function (object) {
  // return false
  //  }
}
```

#### main.js

```js
import util from './components/shared/util.js'
import comp from './components/shared/myComponent.js'
// Vue.component('util', util) this doesn't work
Vue.use(util)

const app = new Vue({
...
components: {
    comp
}).$mount('#app')
```

None of the below work. The error thrown is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEmpty' of undefined`

#### component template

```
<p v-if="util.isEmpty(license)" class="margin-0">N/A</p>
<p v-if="Vue.isEmpty(license)" class="margin-0">N/A</p>
<p v-if="isEmpty(license)" class="margin-0">N/A</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done, are missing of `prototype`. Try this:

**utils.js**

```
export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
      Vue.prototype.isEmpty = function (object) {
        return false // dummy function for now to check if method works
      }
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
<p v-if="isEmpty(license)" class="margin-0">N/A</p>
```

Here a example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-tdx00